# What is the best location for Ruby apps on Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

We have a Ruby application running as a daemon service on our server. Currently the application is located on the Ubuntu machine, under `/usr/share/theapp`.

My question is probably debatable, but I'm just wondering which location would actually be intended as the best, most conventional place for Ruby apps? Is the above OK, or is there a different location intended for daemon apps?

For example, normally, we place PHP web apps hosted with Apache under `/var/www/...`, so I'm thinking there must be a better, good-practice location for placing Ruby apps.

The location probably doesn't matter, so an app won't break if it's hosted and located in a different folder, but I believe there needs to be some form and method to the madness.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to ask this on superuser.com.

Comment: If it's not a web site, it doesn't belong in /var/www.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We put our apps in /usr/local/share, after reading through several descriptions for the various directories typically used.

Any commands in a "bin" sub-directory that should be available to users then gets a soft link to it from /usr/local/bin via a rake task we run at installation.

I agree with the comment that it doesn't make sense to put them under a "www" directory when they don't serve HTML.

Comment: I also managed to find quite an interesting article on Linux folder structure explanation: http://www.debianadmin.com/linux-directory-structure-overview.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm just adding this as an answer to my own question as I think others might find it useful, this comes from http://www.ubuntugeek.com/linux-or-ubuntu-directory-structure.html:

- **/bin** -- binary applications (most of your executable files)
- **/boot** -- files required to boot (such as the kernel, etc)
- **/dev** -- your devices (everything from drives to displays)
- **/etc** -- just about every configuration file for your system
- **/etc/profile.d** -- contains scripts that are run by /etc/profile upon login.
- **/etc/rc.d** -- contains a number of shell scripts that are run on bootup at different run levels. There is also typically an rc.inet1 script to set up networking (in Slackwar), an rc.modules script to load modular device drivers, and an rc.local script that can be edited to run commands desired by the administrator, along the lines of autoexec.bat in DOS.
- **/etc/rc.d/init.d** -- contains most of the initialization scripts themselves on an rpm-based system.
- **/etc/rc.d/rc*.d** -- where "*" is a number corresponding to the default run level. Contains files for services to be started and stopped at that run level. On rpm-based systems, these files are symbolic links to the initialization scripts themselves, which are in * /etc/rc.d/init.d.
- **/etc/skel** -- directory containing several example or skeleton initialization shells. Often contains subdirectories and files used to populate a new user's home directory.
- **/etc/X11** -- configuration files for the X Window system
- **/home** -- locally stored user files and folders
- **/lib** -- system libraries (similar to Program Files)
- **/lost+found** -- lost and found for lost files
- **/media** -- mounted (or loaded) devices such as cdroms, digital cameras, etc.
- **/mnt** -- mounted file systems
- **/opt** -- location for “optionally” installed programs
- **/proc** -- dynamic directory including information about and listing of processes
- **/root** -- “home” folder for the root user
- **/sbin** -- system-only binaries (see /bin)
- **/sys** -- contains information about the system
- **/tmp** -- temporary files
- **/usr** -- applications mainly for regular users
- **/var** -- mainly logs, databases, etc.
- **/usr/local/bin** -- the place to put your own programs. They will not be overwritten with upgrades.
- **/usr/share/doc** -- documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I deploy to `/u/<app_name>/revisions` With the folder named by the datetime of the build. Then I create a symlink to `/u/<app_name>/current`. This was the convention with capistrano, and it works well for just about any kind of application.

#### Example Folder Structure

```
u/foobar/
        |- current* -> /u/foobar/revisions/042920131205
        |- revisions/
                    |- 042920131205/
                                   |- bin/
                                   |- lib/
                                   |- spec/
                                   |- README.md
                                   |- ... (you get the idea)
```

#### Do this by hand

To make this deployment strategy by hand, you are going to be looking at a few really simply commands.

```
date=`date +"%m%d%y%H%M"`
git clone <repo> /u/<app_name>/revisions/$date
ln -s /u/<app_name>/revisions/$date /u/<app_name>/current
```